# Is it possible to activate / deactivate USB-Devices with Python?

Tags: python, usb

I want to code an little tray-tool to disable the Oculus Rift USB Sensors while  I'm not playing.
I would prefer to do this with Python/PyQt5, operating system is Windows 10.

Is there any possibility to achieve this with Python?

Sensors in device manager:

[image: Devices]

**Edit:**
What I want to achieve is to entirely disable / enable these devices in Windows like it would be if I disable the device in device manager:

[image: device manager]

Comment: Did you find a way?

Comment: I tried to use PyUSB with the libusb-1.0 backend - It does not work either (neither reset nor dispose_resources)

Answer (score 0):

So you want to eject the removable drive if i got it right. Have you tried calling powershell from python? Here is an example

https://github.com/iamgyz/usbEjector/blob/master/usb_eject.py

Comment: I do not think the Oculus Rift USB Sensors are recognized as a drive. I think this is a general question about USB devices.